# How to identify the GC Finalizer thread?

Tags: .net, multithreading, finalizer

I have a .NET (C#) multi-threaded application and I want to know if a certain method runs inside the Finalizer thread.

I've tried using Thread.CurrentThread.Name but it doesn't work (returns null).

Anyone knows how can I query the current thread to discover if it's the Finalizer thread?

Comment: Why do you need to know which thread is running GC?

Comment: my fuction runs code that I do not want to run during finalization

Comment: Besides does it really matters? There is a problem I want to find how to solve.

Comment: You should never be offended when someone asks "why do you want to do that" in response to a question; often, they've spotted a pattern and they're trying to determine whether or not they can suggest a cleaner solution to your actual problem. Obviously, this can sometimes irk you if you [cont'd]

Comment: know what you're doing, but you shouldn't feel as if they're questioning your judgement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best way to identify a thread is through its managed id:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
```

Since a finalizer always runs in the GC's thread you can create a finalizer that will save the thread id (or the thread object) in a static valiable.

Sample:

```
public class ThreadTest {
    public static Thread GCThread;

    ~ThreadTest() {
        ThreadTest.GCThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
    }
}
```

in your code just create an instance of this class and do a garbage collection:

```
public static void Main() {
    ThreadTest test = new ThreadTest();
    test = null;
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    Console.WriteLine(ThreadTest.GCThread.ManagedThreadID);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If debugging is an option you can easily find it using WinDbg + SoS.dll. The `!threads` command displays all managed threads in the application and the finalizer thread is specifically highlighted with a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Y Low's code could be improved slightly...

```
public static void Main()
{
  ThreadTest test = new ThreadTest();
  test = null;

  GC.Collect();
  GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

  Console.WriteLine(ThreadTest.GCThread.ManagedThreadID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible even using the debugging APIs, see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2006/03/02/expose-finalizer-thread.aspx) blog post for more info.