# How does the garbage collector work with unit tests?

Tags: .net, sql, unit-testing, garbage-collection

Recently, I asked (and answered) a question on StackOverflow about why a unit test would work when run by itself and then fail sporadically when run with the whole batch of unit tests.  See here: [SQL Server and TransactionScope (with MSDTC): Sporadically can't get connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072986/sql-server-and-transactionscope-with-msdtc-sporadically-cant-get-connection)

Unit tests passing when running one at a time and then failing when run together is a classic sign that something is seriously wrong with the code.

I discovered that there is a bit of a resource-leak.  Because of a subtle error causing connections to a SQL server to not be released, I was running out of connections and tests were failing.  AFAIK, this works almost exactly like a memory leak; connections are allocated from a connection pool and never freed just as memory can be allocated and then not freed.

However, this does leave me with a puzzling question?  What is the difference between running my tests one at a time and running them as a suite?  If the tests pass when run one at a time and then fail when run together, then there must be some sort of clean-up happening between test runs that happens only when the tests are run one at a time.

I conjecture that this could have something to do with what the .net garbage collector does or doesn't do between the tests.  In one case, connections are freed between tests; in another case, they aren't.

How can I explain this?

**Update**: To those of you asking about the specifics of the code, it's rather simple.  I declare a new `TransactionScope` object in my Setup method and dispose it in my `Teardown` method.  However, The problem test was a data-driven test with 100 test cases; the code under test populated a `SqlDataReader` object from a select statement using the SqlHelper class and then didn't call the close method on the `SqlDataReader`.  Because I used the SqlHelper class to get the SqlDataReader, I expected that the connections were handled for me.  Not so!

**But to clarify**, I'm not asking about my specific situation.  What I want to know is: generally, how are resources freed between tests?  I would imagine this would be some application of the garbage collector.  I wonder if the garbage collector could still be cleaning up a previous test as the next test runs (race condition?)

**Update: What I know about garbage collection with Unit Tests.** Following my own curiosity, I pulled out the unit tests that were failing because a connection was left open by the `SqlDataReader` object.  I tried adding `System.GC.Collect()` to the end of each test.  This successfully freed the connections, but does impose an ~50% performance penalty.

Comment: If you are running out of connections because you do not release enough of them between tests, I'd suspect that there is a problem with your tear down methods. When running them one at a time, the OS takes care of some tear down, but run as a suite your resource usage persists longer.

Comment: Maybe you just need some more `Dispose` or `Close` calls somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Garbage collection is a periodic background task.  In specific, there's a thread that does nothing but finalize objects that have already been marked as dead.  By running one test at a time, you're giving that thread a chance finalize objects so as to close the connections.

Comment: Really?  Can you point me to some documentation that shows the the GC ordinarily operates on its own thread?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318462/how-to-identify-the-gc-finalizer-thread

Comment: GC can actually stop all threads briefly, but it also runs finalizers in a thread, as explained in the link.

Comment: Even if this was accepted as answer it isn't the true reason. On machines with lots of resources, it can take a very long time for the GC to be triggered, especially for finalizable objects which always survive the first generation GC. The true reason is that appdomains are being created for test runs (which may be one test or a test batch), and when those are unloaded all objects in that appdomain are finalized, which deterministically cleans up any leaked resources right then.

Comment: @Lucero: Sure, that's also part of it.  Memory pressure triggers GC, so tests might not generate enough to do it quickly.  I don't know the exact algorithm, in terms of how much it's based on a timeout and how much on pressure, but the details aren't particularly important in this case.

Comment: @Steven, sure, if the GC happens to run between the tests and the finalizer thread is fast enough to run the finalizers, you'll not notice the resource leak. Still it isn't deterministic, and running the GC alone does nothing to solve the issue, as a GC run needs to be followed by a finalization for the handles to be freed (for instance, if a finalizer blocks the finalizer thread for some time, the other finalizers will not be executed and therefore no resources would be released in that timespan).

Comment: @Lucero: All of which translates to "Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't", just like the OP said.  The right answer would be to use IDsposable properly, as Gabe suggested.

Answer (score 4):

That sounds feasible, yes. It wouldn't be at all surprising for the unit test framework to request that the garbage collector runs between tests.

Alternatively, the different pattern of execution may just naturally trigger garbage collection when they're run one after another. The trouble with analyzing this sort of thing is it's all very dynamic - and will vary from test run to test run.

Don't forget it probably didn't have to free *all* the connections between tests - just enough to keep them running...

The garbage collector itself is unlikely to behave any differently in unit tests, unless the test runner process is configured in a particular way. On the other hand, whether you run the tests in the debugger or not *will* affect how eager the garbage collector is, etc.

Comment: Jon, in case you missed it, Lucero mentioned that it apparently unloads the entire AppDomain, which should get rid of any leaks.

Answer (score 2):

Usually each test run is performed in a separate appdomain for several reasons. Now when the appdomain is unloaded it will release the resources associated with it, so that the open connections are closed and therefore preventing the "leak" to manifest itself.

See also [Cbrumme's blog on this topic](https://web.archive.org/web/20151207043745/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/cbrumme/archive/2004/02/20/77460.aspx).

Comment: Ah, ok.  If it unloads the AppDomain then there's no need to force garbage collection in between.

Comment: Exactly. Since the only way to unload assemblies is by having them in a separate appdomain and unload the appdomain, the "resource leak cleanup" is a side-effect of it.

Comment: Well, whether it's a side-effect depends on your intent.  I've had to use AppDomains to clean up leaked resources, with the unloading of assemblies being a side-effect. :-)

Comment: Since it changes the behavior of one test vs. a test batch, it is a side-effect in this case IMHO. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Unit tests passing when running one at
>   a time and then failing when run
>   together is a classic sign that
>   something is seriously wrong with the
>   code.

I  think there is something seriously wrong with the way you have written your unit tests. Each test should run independently of other tests. One way to do it is ensure you have a setup and teardown methods(`[SetUp][TearDown]`) which create and cleanup the environment necessary for a test to run.

In your Setup method you create your connection, in your teardown method you dispose it. Now before running each test, your Setup method will be called and after each test your teardown method will be called and this will ensure that you don't leak any resources.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, multiple issues here!

First, you want your unit test series to be FAST. Don't hit the database to test business logic, etc.

Second, if your production code is leaking resources (?) that is your main problem. Don't fix that problem by changing how you setup/teardown your test code. Now, if your test code is allocating system resorces but not disposing correctly, you need to fix that the right way and not by trying to control when the garbage collector runs. You should not have to worry about that.

Third, you really should not have to create a TransactionScope in your unit tests. This makes no sense to me. There is something wrong with the coding style you are using in your test code. Unit tests are not just any automated tests, such as integration tests or system tests. Unit tests are small and focused tests that test the behavior of a SMALL piece of production code in ISOLATION, that is independently from all the other production code.

Now, a tip about the leaking resources. A good programming practice is to use the using-statement when creating a disposable object to guarantee those resources are properly disposed.

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = ...)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: How can you use `SqlDataReader` with `using`.  It doesn't have a `dispose()` method.

Comment: Dude it does just open up your Object Browser and check it out, it inherits disposable DbDataReader - see type declaration below. Btw, most of these database connection related types have to be disposable as they wrap various OS resources that get allocated when used. Closing a reader is in effect disposing it. A benefit of using-statements is that they dispose even if an exception is thrown , in effect sugar for try { ... } finally { foo.Dispose();}


public class SqlDataReader : DbDataReader, IDataReader, IDisposable, IDataRecord